# get type of member memberpointer points to

Tags: c++, types, member-pointers

I would like to extract the type of the member a member pointer points to.

```
template<someType myClass::*member>
void demo(myClass& instance, void* ptr) {
    instance.*member = *reinterpret_cast<someType*>(ptr);  // can the someType in this line be deduced from member?
}
```

I tried using `decltype` as suggested in the comments, however I have issues with this:

```
instance.*member= static_cast<decltype(instance.*member)>((*buffer)[offset]);
```

`buffer` is a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>>`,
`someType` is `uint32_t`

I get the following error message:

> error: invalid static_cast from type
>   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type
>   {aka unsigned char}’ to type ‘uint32_t& {aka unsigned int&}’

As far as I understand `decltype(instance.*member)` with `member` defined as `uint32_t instance::*member` yields a *reference* `uint32_t&` rather than `uint32_t`. I tried to pass instance by value and the error remains. I am aware of `std::remove_reference` however, I do not understand how the reference gets to be there in the first place.

A further improvement would be if I could extract the `someType` without a class instance. However I have no clue how to achieve this, while I can get the class without a pointer by having the std lib like:

```
template <T*>
struct removePointer {
  typedef T type;
}
```

I have no Idea how to write this in a form where I can get the `someType` part of the class, without knowing the class first. I could write something like the following however I would still have to pass the class naem and typename explicitly, is there a way to extract these automatically? Furthermore the following doe not compile in the first place (http://ideone.com/8VlKO4):
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
template <class C,typename T, T C::*v>
struct getPointerType {
typedef T type;
};

class Test {
int value;
};

int main() {
int Test::*member=nullptr;
cout << typeid(getPointerType<Test, int, decltype(member)>::type) << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: On c++11 you can use decltype() to explicitly deduce the desired type. If you don't have c++11 enabled, you may get off with `typeof`/`__typeof__`.

Comment: @oakad could you help me with the decltype part? I updated the question to show the issues I have with decltype and added a pitch about using templates, however I am afraid the idea with templates wont work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting class and member type from pointer to member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228958/getting-class-and-member-type-from-pointer-to-member-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, it's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, so I will focus on the updated part.

Clearly, you can not pass types (derived from `decltype`) as value arguments to the template. Moreover, you can not pass non constexpr values as template arguments (so you can not just stick the `member` variable into the template argument and expect it to compile).

However, you can rely on compiler to be able to deduce a correct function to call on non `costexpr` variable:

```
template <class C, typename T>
T getPointerType(T C::*v);

class Test {
    int value;
};

int main() {
    int Test::*member=nullptr;
    cout << typeid(decltype(member)).name() << std::endl;
    cout << typeid(decltype(getPointerType(member))).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above will print:

```
M4Testi //int Test::*
i       //int
```

It is, of course, possible to "abuse" the template substitution even more:

```
template <typename M>
struct getPointerType {
   template <typename C, typename T>
   static T get_type(T C::*v);

   typedef decltype(get_type(static_cast<M>(nullptr))) type;
};

class Test {
    int value;
};

int main() {
    int Test::*member=nullptr;
    cout << typeid(getPointerType<decltype(member)>::type).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the expected "i".

Comment: This does exactly what I am looking for. If I understand you there is no way to come up with the library like `getPointerType<member>::type` syntax, since `member` is not `const`. Would it be possible to achieve `getPointerType<decltype(member)>::type`? Or maybe `getPointerType(member).type` (I tried this: "template <class C, typename T>
struct getPointerType {
 getPointerType(T C::*v) {}
 typedef T type;
};", however this results in an error that the template arguments are missing)

Comment: Ok, edited the post to include `getPointerType<decltype(member)>::type`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using template specialization technique :

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct member_type_helper;

template <class C, class T>
struct member_type_helper<T C::*> { using type = T; };

template <class T>
struct member_type
    : member_type_helper<typename std::remove_cvref<T>::type> {};

// Helper type
template <class T>
using member_type_t = member_type<T>::type;
```

Example of usage :

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo { int i; };

int main()
{
    auto                ptr1 = &Foo::i;
    auto const&         ptr2 = &Foo::i;
    volatile auto const ptr3 = &Foo::i; // let's go crazy

    // prints true true true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << std::same_as<int, member_type_t<decltype(ptr1)>> << '\n'
              << std::same_as<int, member_type_t<decltype(ptr2)>> << '\n'
              << std::same_as<int, member_type_t<decltype(ptr3)>> << '\n';
}
```

I guess `std::remove_cvref` might be an overkill for most usage, but hey, it's free. If your compiler isn't >C++20 compliant, you could use `std::remove_cv` instead (> C++11).

---