# Getting class and member type from pointer to member variable

Tags: c++, boost

For example:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T ptr)
{
  typedef GET_CLASS_TYPE(T) ClassT;
  typedef GET_VALUE_TYPE(T) ValueT;
  // ...
}

struct Bar
{
  int var;
};

foo(&Bar::var);
```

Inside the last function call to `foo(...)`, `ClassT` should be `Bar` and `ValueT` should be `int`.

How can I do this with plain C++ (can't use C++11 features), or boost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not aware of any out-of-the-box Boost type trait to do this, but the same can be written by yourself using template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct member_pointer_class;

template<typename Class, typename Value>
struct member_pointer_class<Value Class::*>
{
    typedef Class type;
};

template<typename T>
struct member_pointer_value;

template<typename Class, typename Value>
struct member_pointer_value<Value Class::*>
{
    typedef Value type;
};

// TEST
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

struct Bar
{
    int var;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T ptr)
{
    // test the code
    typedef typename member_pointer_class<T>::type ClassT;
    typedef typename member_pointer_value<T>::type ValueT;
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((boost::is_same<ClassT, Bar>::value), "member_pointer_class is the same as Bar");
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((boost::is_same<ValueT, int>::value), "member_pointer_value is the same as int");
}

int main()
{
    foo(&Bar::var);
}
```

Explanation:

Using template deduction we extract the interesting types of the member pointer - the typedefs `member_pointer_class<T>::type` and `member_pointer_value<T>::type` are defined to the appropriate types. [`typename` is required for disambiguation in templates.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) The code can be also used for pointer to member functions.

If the type is not a pointer to member, the `member_pointer_class<T>::type` gives a compiler error.