# Pointers to member arrays with differing sizes

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, pointer-to-member

Suppose I have a class with two array members, of the same element type but different sizes:

```
struct X
{
  string a[2];
  string b[3];
};

constexpr auto array_members = std::array{ &X::a, &X::b };
```

This does not compile, because the two arrays (having different lengths) have incompatible types.

Is there a common type to which both member pointers can be assigned?

I have also tried `static_cast<string (X::*)[]>(&X::a)` but this also does not compile because of the incomplete array type.

I cannot use `offsetof` because it needs to work with non-standard-layout classes.

This may be a workaround:

```
using array_type = decltype(X::b);
auto const array_members = std::array{
  reinterpret_cast<array_type X::*>(&X::a), // cannot be constexpr
  &X::b
};
```

but I am concerned about invoking undefined behavior. Although I am confident that there are no out-of-bounds element references at run-time, we do create one-past-the-end pointers to `a`, which given the type of `b` appear to be in-bounds. I am not sure whether this goes against the spec. Also it would be convenient if I could use `constexpr` which is incompatible with `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Yes, it's called a Union.

Comment: `std::vector` lets you get around all of this as the size is not part of the type.

Comment: @NathanOliver That loses the compile-time size information for the member.

Comment: Replacing `std::array` with `std::tuple` could be an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have an array of member pointers to members of different types.

Instead of a member pointer, you could instead use some kind of function that returns span to the member:

```
template<auto m>
constexpr auto getter = [](X& x) noexcept
                        // X could be deduced from m for extra genericity
                        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228958
{

    return span{x.*m, std::size(x.*m)};
};

constexpr auto array_members = std::array{ +getter<&X::a>, +getter<&X::b> };
```

[No assembly generated :)](https://godbolt.org/z/K5mn5C) at zero optimization level (until you actually call the functions of course). `array_members` is an array of function pointers. Example usage:

```
X x;
span a = array_members[0](x);
a[0] = "test";
```

This uses `span`, which is not in C++17 standard library, so you need to use another implementation of it.

Comment: Compile time type-erasure... done through a templated lambda. Well done. I wish I could upvote two times

Comment: Thanks - what is the effect of the `+` on the getters... and why does `&` not have the same effect?

Comment: OK I found this question which explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822131/resolving-ambiguous-overload-on-function-pointer-and-stdfunction-for-a-lambda

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to achieve what you want:

```
#include <variant>
#include <array>

struct X
{
    std::variant<array<string, 2>, array<string, 3>> a;
    std::variant<array<string, 2>, array<string, 3>> b;

};

 constexpr auto array_members = std::array{ &X::a, &X::b };
 array<string, 3> arr;
 std::variant<array<string, 2>, array<string, 3>> a = arr;
 cout<<"test array: "<<std::get<1>(a)[0];
 //cout<<std::get<0>(a)[0]; will throw
```

The drawback is that both `a` and `b` will occupy memory as much as `array<string, 3>`.  `std::variant` is type safe though.

Live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/SXGyf9)